# Check if in the List occurs object with boolean = true

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have the following List:

```
ArrayList<ConsumerWarehouse> consumerWarehouse = new ArrayList<ConsumerWarehouse>();
```

The `ConsumerWarehouse` constructor:

```
public ConsumerWarehouse(double length, double width, double height)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        calculateRoomSpace();
        SPACE_ID = countSpace.incrementAndGet();
        this.booked = false;
        consumerWarehouse.add(this);
    }
```

Created object and called method:

```
ConsumerWarehouse warehouseNo1 = new ConsumerWarehouse(10,10,3);
warehouseNo1.setBooked(true);
```

The setBooked method sets the 'booked' variable to true.
I would like to write a method that would show me all objects that are in consumerWarehouse list and have the value 'booked' set to false, an example of method name:

```
public void displayFreeConsumerWarehouse()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < consumerWarehouse.size(); i++)
        {
            if() // TODO
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what condition I should set here, could you please suggest some?

Comment: if(!isBooked) maybe? ...the method return true or false

Comment: you can access your item in the list using consumerWarehouse.get(i), but there are "nicer" ways to build a loop like this. 
for (ConsumverWarehouse warehouse : consumerWarehouses) {
   if (warehouse.isBooked) {
...
}
}
Or, even nicer, you could use a stream.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you have a `isBooked()` or `getBooked()` method exposing that property.
If you have a `isBooked()` method, it would be:

```
public void displayFreeConsumerWarehouse()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < consumerWarehouse.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!consumerWarehouse.get(i).isBooked())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java stream solution:

```
public void displayFreeConsumerWarehouse(){
    consumerWarehouse.stream()
            .filter(warehouse -> !warehouse.isBooked())
            .forEach(warehouse -> System.out.println(warehouse));
}
```